# API Rate Limiting by IP

Tags: api, http, http-headers, rate-limiting

I was looking at how rate limiting is done, and it seems that a lot of APIs (including the StackOverflow v1 API) rate limit by IP or limit API keys to usage on a certain domain.  How is this done reliably?

When I look at a request generated by an XHR to my API, it has a referrer (usually) and a remote address.  I thought the remote address would be promising, but it looks like that's the address of the user using the website, not of the site making the requests.  The referrer looks like it's not always sent, though I suppose when it's there, one could look up the IP corresponding to the server.

My point is: it must be possible, since some of the big names do it; how do they do it?

Comment: Not 100% sure what you mean. They're going to look at the remote IP address that is the source of the request. What do you mean "the site making the requests"?

Comment: So, if a request is made by an XHR from a webpage, they'd rate-limit by the webpage, not the person visiting the site, right?

Comment: They want to rate limit / pass out API keys based on the application, not on the users of the application, right?

Comment: Most big names have an API key and API secret(if they need auth) to access the api methods. If you are ok with that approach, you could cap usage per api key, possibly?

Answer (score 3):

In fraud arena these are called velocity controls, and in traffic management it is similar to "traffic shaping". Basically you are permitting a limited usage per period of time, so that for instance you might only permit 10 requests/minute/ip address.

For each 'request', determine the remote address ( getpeername() in C) this function will always be the remote users ip address. Then simply count per period of time how may requests are processed, and if you exceed limits, do whatever. In pseudo code

```
Get block for remote ip
If time-now is new window, then reset usage to zero
Add one to usage count
If usage > allowance then .....
Else if usage > allowance*0.75 then slow-down 
Else ok
```

While I've shown a single period, most implementations usually average over several periods, such as every minute for an hour etc. they would also tend to allow bursts and only restrict sustained loads, but this depends on the profile you wish to allow.

If this is for an API, it is normal to simply slow down the request rather than providing a hard error. There is no guarantee the client at thr other end will handle the error. If it is a user screen, then you can display limits exceeded.

You can of course restrict by any dimension you wish, ip address, refer, browser type!, pageurl, cookie. If you are using getpeername, be aware that several concurrent users can all have the same remote ip address if they are behind a common private router.

Answer (score 1):

You either use the remote address of the request or the  first ip in the x-forwarded-for header.

You use the header only when your app is behind a reverse proxy that you trust or you run on PaaS for instance. You need to control how many levels you trust. Check the nginx module real-ip.

Using the ip address is a very common pattern for anonymous traffic because at this point you know nothing about the user. Once the user is authenticated (being a person or an app) is better to use its id instead of the ip.